# Python: How to install utils.metrics module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run some time series deep learning algorithms, and they require some modules. However, when I run the the following code it gives me an error:

```
import pickle
import warnings
from math import sqrt

import lightgbm as lgb
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd  # Basic library for all of our dataset operations
import pmdarima as pm
import tensorflow as tf
import xgboost as xgb
from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization
from fbprophet import Prophet
from gluonts.dataset.common import ListDataset
from gluonts.evaluation.backtest import make_evaluation_predictions
from gluonts.model.deepar import DeepAREstimator
from gluonts.mx.trainer import Trainer
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model, svm
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, cross_val_score
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AR
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA, ARMA
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing, SimpleExpSmoothing
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
from tqdm import tqdm

from utils.metrics import evaluate
```

And this is the error it shows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b033063c2c35> in <module>
 29 from tqdm import tqdm
 30 
---> 31 from utils.metrics import evaluate

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.metrics'
```

I tried for many days to find the '''utils.metrics''', but I didn't find anything. Please help me if you have any idea to fix this problem. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: This is how the folder containing the code looks like.

[image]

Comment: there must be a ```utils.py``` file accompanying the script file you are running, they should be in the same folder

Comment: @Shar Thank you, I will check out the file and see.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see an example of how has to be constructed your folder in order to have the evaluate function:

https://www.programcreek.com/python/?code=jakc4103%2FDFQ%2FDFQ-master%2Futils%2Fsegmentation%2Futils.py#

As you can see, there are a `metrics.py` file in the `utils` folder which contains the class `Evaluator`.

Here is a folder example:

```
main_folder
|_utils                 #it is a folder
  |_metrics.py
|_code1.py
|_code2.py
```

`code1.py` and `code2.py` are only examples of names for py codes that you can have in your main folder.

**EDIT**

Code that should be in `metrics.py`:

```py
import numpy as np


class Evaluator(object):
    def __init__(self, num_class):
        self.num_class = num_class
        self.confusion_matrix = np.zeros((self.num_class,)*2)

    def Pixel_Accuracy(self):
        Acc = np.diag(self.confusion_matrix).sum() / self.confusion_matrix.sum()
        return Acc

    def Pixel_Accuracy_Class(self):
        Acc = np.diag(self.confusion_matrix) / self.confusion_matrix.sum(axis=1)
        Acc = np.nanmean(Acc)
        return Acc

    def Mean_Intersection_over_Union(self):
        MIoU = np.diag(self.confusion_matrix) / (
                    np.sum(self.confusion_matrix, axis=1) + np.sum(self.confusion_matrix, axis=0) -
                    np.diag(self.confusion_matrix))
        MIoU = np.nanmean(MIoU)
        return MIoU

    def Frequency_Weighted_Intersection_over_Union(self):
        freq = np.sum(self.confusion_matrix, axis=1) / np.sum(self.confusion_matrix)
        iu = np.diag(self.confusion_matrix) / (
                    np.sum(self.confusion_matrix, axis=1) + np.sum(self.confusion_matrix, axis=0) -
                    np.diag(self.confusion_matrix))

        FWIoU = (freq[freq > 0] * iu[freq > 0]).sum()
        return FWIoU

    def _generate_matrix(self, gt_image, pre_image):
        mask = (gt_image >= 0) & (gt_image < self.num_class)
        label = self.num_class * gt_image[mask].astype('int') + pre_image[mask]
        count = np.bincount(label, minlength=self.num_class**2)
        confusion_matrix = count.reshape(self.num_class, self.num_class)
        return confusion_matrix

    def add_batch(self, gt_image, pre_image):
        assert gt_image.shape == pre_image.shape
        self.confusion_matrix += self._generate_matrix(gt_image, pre_image)

    def reset(self):
        self.confusion_matrix = np.zeros((self.num_class,) * 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In the example in your link, the folder is already constructed. However in my case, although I downloaded the folder with all the files from github, I don't know how to construct it. I run the ipynb in jupyter and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: I would try to give you a folder example in my answer

Comment: If it still doesn't work for you, please give us a capture of your actual folder in order to give more specific support.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added a picture of my folder. I am trying to run 02-Forecasting_models.ipynb.

Comment: Did you insert inside `utils` folder the file `metrics.py`? If you did it, Did you insert the code which I include in my answer?

Comment: The file `metrics.py` already exists in `utils`, and I added the code you wrote inside the `metrics.py` file, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235140/discussion-between-f-nielsen-and-said-maanan).

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with Python codes from this tutorial (https://github.com/jiwidi/time-series-forecasting-with-python), you have to save their metrics.py document into your utils folder.

https://github.com/jiwidi/time-series-forecasting-with-python/tree/master/utils